# Displaying compressed footnotes as 1-3 and referencing footnotes

Tags: citing, footnotes, incompatibility, footmisc

I can do both things separately but I can't manage to implement both together due to incompatibilities with `footnoterange` and `footmisc` packages.

1. To display compressed footnotes I do:

```
\usepackage{footnoterange}
...
some text\begin{footnoterange}\footnote{hello}\footnote{world}\footnote{how are you}
\end{footnoterange}
```

And works like this:

[image]
[image]

2. Now, to reference a footnote I do:

```
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
...
other text\footnote{bad\label{ref:1}}. See\footref{ref:1}.
```

And works fine too:

[image]

[image]

3. But when I try to do both ways together there are incompatibilities between both packages and Latex can't compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{footnoterange}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
some text\begin{footnoterange}\footnote{hello}\footnote{world}\footnote{how are you}
\end{footnoterange}
other text\footnote{bad\label{ref:1}}. See\footref{ref:1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Please include a MWE (a complete example of what you mean by "both ways together" that we can just copy and compile to see what's wrong).

Comment: (I just tried playing around with both packages together, and I don't see any incompatibilities; using `\footref` within the `footnoterange` environment, as expected, give something ugly, but I don't get any compilation errors.)

Comment: The issue seems to be specifically the `[symbol]` option; without it the file compiles fine.

Comment: Okay, it is not specifically anything about `footmisc`. You get the same error if you just load `footenoterange` and change the footnote numbering to symbols via `\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}`. If you use `\alph` or `\roman` there are also no problems.

Comment: The problem aside: do you really want to have a "footnote range" using symbols? That would be extremely unclear, in my opinion.

Comment: The problem is I am using two footnote types. One with symbols (with which I do not need the `footnoterange`) but another with numbers, with which I would like to use it.

Comment: @WillieWong Ah but with what you told me I solved the problem. I just did a renewcommand for my symbols footnote and then it works without a problem. Thank you a lot! :)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally at issue is not that `footmisc` is not compatible with `footnoterange`, is is that `footnoterange` (before version 1.0c 2019-11-24, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnoterange) was not compatible with using symbols for the footnote marks.

One sees already this problem with the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{footnoterange}

\renewcommand*\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\begin{document}
Text\begin{footnoterange}\footnote{First}\footnote{second}\footnote{Third}\end{footnoterange}
\end{document}
```

This manifested in your case because loading the `footmisc` package with either the `symbol` or `symbol*` options just do some version of the `\renewcommand` above to set the marks used for footnotes.

There is no problem with using `footnoterange` with the `\arabic`, `\Alph`, `\alph`, `\Roman`, `\roman` numbering schemes, nor with the `\alphalph` numbering schemes defined by the `alphalph` package.

So what's the problem, I am not 100% sure *why* the problem manifests in the way it does, but you can trace it to how `footnoterange` works: for various reasons it chooses to store the values of `\arabic{footnote}` and `\thefootnote` temporarily and use them to build the actual footnotes. The command to store the latter, in the package, was

```
\edef\fnr@formated{\thefootnote}
```

The full expansion in `\edef`, when it hits the `\fnsymbol`, did very weird things, in part because `\fnsymbol` sets the marks in mathmode.

(Incidentally, I ran into a similar problem myself [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448234/kpfonts-error-with-environ-package-and-write).)

A possible solution (though I haven't tested it seriously) is to replace the offending `\edef` with

```
\protected@edef\fnr@formated{\thefootnote}
```

which with my limited testing should fix the problem, at least with regards to the symbol footnotes. (This was applied in version 1.0c 2019-11-24 of the `footnoterange` package, *because of this answer*.)

---

This, however, does not address the original intended question of the OP. If the OP had successfully called `\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}`, the output will be all footnotes in symbols, instead of what seems to be [desired](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516962/displaying-compressed-footnotes-as-1-3-and-referencing-footnotes?noredirect=1#comment1307445_516962).

One way to do this is to manually create a second series of footnote commands, such as

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\secondFootnote{\xdef\@thefnmark{$\dagger$}\@footnotemark\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Test\footnote{Text}

Test\secondFootnote{Test2} 

Test\footnote{Test}

\end{document}
```

The above code makes every `\secondFootnote` display a `\dagger` for the mark, but you can play with counters to change that. How it interacts with `\footref` from `footmisc` probably requires also some tuning.

Alternatively, if one doesn't mind the numbering of the numeric footnotes skipping numbers, one can just, as the OP suggested, `\renewcommand*\thefootnote` prior to making a symbol footnote and change it back afterwards.